# What tools to use for efficient link building?

Tags: seo, google, links, link-building

As most SEO experts keep saying, it is not just the content that you have - but also a hefty amount of *quality* incoming links to your content that is important - these are the two ways to get to the top of the search results.

The question is where do I find the incoming links?

One way I know is [Google blog search](http://blogsearch.google.com/), it can be used to find blogs with related information to your content and some allow to leave comments. The comments usually consist of your name, e-mail and website. If you put your keyword instead of your name, then the keyword turns into a link to your website. Unfortunately most blogs put the `rel=nofollow` attribute on such links, but some blogs don't do that.

What other ways are there to **find quality pages to put keywords links** back to your website?

Quality link usually means:

- located on a page with relevant content
- does not have a `rel=nofollow` attribute in the `<a>` tag
- has a relevant keyword as in `<a href="website">keyword&lt;</a>`
- the page with the link has high [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) (3+) and [TrustRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrustRank)

Comment: If you can add your link that easily, it almost certainly isn't a quality link.

Comment: I didnt say anything about easy ... It can be hard, question is how?

Comment: By easy I meant you simply submit your link or comment on a blog, etc. Finding those links may not be the easiest thing in the world but getting those links are easy compared to truly quality links.

Comment: I can send an email asking the blog owner to publish my article, with links in it ... It is finding these blogs that is the hard part.

Comment: @John Conde: Yea, what he describes sound suspiciously like comment-spamming. If you're going to comment on someone's blog, do so because you have something to say or want to respond to the post, and use your real name, or at least a nickname or company name, not search keywords. Don't use blogs without `nofollow` as a way to trick Google into thinking people are actually voluntarily linking to your site (which Google treats as a "vote" for that page). It's basically trying to game the system.

Answer (score 4):

Often, a link with `nofollow` is just as important as one without. Remember, links are for *people*, not search engines. If you have something useful to add to the conversation then others are more inclined to check out your site. The side effect of that is you may get natural links from other webmasters that visit.

The other strategy, particularly if you are a product/service shop, is to send out press releases to all relevant news websites/blogs. Make sure it's new-worthy, of course! You are likely to gather links naturally through reposts of your news.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `ontolo.com` their free link building tools are some of the best there are. You'll probably be most interested in the link query generator it allows you to select the type of link you want to research and use the keyword you give it to generate a list of common queries used to find those types of links (for example *powered by wordpress intitle:keyword* would likely return a list of blogs related to your keyword). If you've got a little budget their paid tool runs the queries for you and returns a lot of additional information such as PageRank of the URL, PageRank of the domain, relevance to your query (not sure how they determine it but it seems pretty accurate) and more.

Answer (score 1):

[iMacros for Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) is a good and free/open source tool to help with link building. Here is a <del>[nice tutorial](http://www.macrorecorder.org/)</del> [another tutorial](http://wiki.imacros.net/Tutorials).

Comment: Looks like an amazing tool, once quality websites to put links at are found. Thank you!